# ループバックアドレスの範囲と用途について

Tags: windows, network

ループバックインターフェイスは「自分自身を判別する為に使われる仮想的インターフェイス」とWeb上で出てきます。

用途としては以下の認識でいます。

１：「IPアドレスを仮想的に複数所有する事ができ物理的機器が動作している限りループバックインターフェイスは機能している為、物理的インターフェイスの予備として仮想的にルーティングしておくことができる」
２：TCP/IP通信がしっかり機能しているか確認する為のもの
３：「ループバックインターフェイスのIPアドレスとして登録できる範囲は127.0.0.0~127.255255.255まで」

ただ、現在学習している環境で２つのRTのみがある状態で、それぞれのRTのループバックインターフェイスに192.168.1.1/32、192.168.2.1/32を割り当ててpingを通すという課題があります。
（それぞれのRTは１つの物理線でのみ繋がっています）

- ループバックインターフェイスに127.0~以外のIPアドレスを割り振れるのでしょうか？
- 上記に書いたループバックインターフェイスの特徴だと、「１」は実際に機能させている環境で冗長的目的の為に利用するようなイメージに対して「２」はpingのような確認的作業の為に利用するイメージなので実際のインフラ環境ではどのように利用されているのか知りたいです
- ダイナミックルーティングでOSPF等？でルート優先度を決める時に判別に利用されるループバックの値とはまた別ものでしょうか？

知識が浅いものでネット上に既にある情報では理解が難しかったので、どなたかご解答いただける方宜しくお願いします。

Comment: "RT" は何の略でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

> - ループバックインターフェイスに127.0~以外のIPアドレスを割り振れるのでしょうか？

機器やOSによってはできます。例えば、Linuxでは、

```
sudo ip addr addr 192.168.1.1/24 dev lo
```

Microsoft Windowsでは、

```
netsh interface ipv4 add address name="Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1" addr=192.168.1.1 mask=255.255.255.0
```

Cisco IOSでは、

```
interface loopback 0
  ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
```

とすることで、ループバックインターフェースに192.168.1.1が割り当てられます。このような設定の実例として、[LVS](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Virtual_Server)のダイレクトルーティングを行うときに実サーバーに設定する事があります。ただ、かなり特殊な設定であり、通常の構成では設定しません。

なお、IPv6を有効にしている場合は、127.0.0.1/8だけではなく、自動的に ::1 も割り当てられます。

> - 上記に書いたループバックインターフェイスの特徴だと、「１」は実際に機能させている環境で冗長的目的の為に利用するようなイメージに対して「２」はpingのような確認的作業の為に利用するイメージなので実際のインフラ環境ではどのように利用されているのか知りたいです

そもそもの理解が間違っています。ループバックインターフェースは「一つのコンピューターの中だけでネットワーク通信を行う」ためにあります。

現在のほとんどのアプリケーションは、プログラム間のデータのやり取りににネットワーク通信を使用しています。これは、異なるコンピューター間で通信するにはネットワークを利用せざるを得ないからです。システムというのは、異なるアプリケーション(Webサーバーやデーターベース等)の集合体であり、規模が大きくなると複数のコンピューターにあるアプリケーションが相互にネットワーク通信を行いながら、一つのシステムを作っています。そういったことに対応するために、初めからネットワーク通信を前提にした作りにした方が良いというわけです。

規模が小さいシステムはでどうでしょうか？その中で通信しあううある二つのアプリケーションが同じコンピューター上にあることもよくあります。そのような場合でネットワーク通信を行うとしても、わざわざ物理的なNIC(ネットワークインターフェースカード)を経由して通信するのは無駄です。こういうときに使われるのが、ループパックインターフェースであり、TCP/IPであれば自動的に割り当てられるループバックアドレス(127.0.0.0/8と::1)を相手のアドレスに指定することで実現しています。

つまり、ループバックインターフェースは、物理的なNICの代わりに使うわけではありませんし、ネットワーク自体の動作の確認に使うわけでもありません。内部通信に限れば、ループバックインターフェースの方が物理的なNICより優秀(高速かつ安全)ですし、ネットワークが動いているか見るために実際の現場で`ping 127.0.0.1`などと打つことは無意味です。ただ、ネットワークを通じたサービスの動作確認、例えばWebサーバーを動かしたときに、正常に動いているかを確認するために、そのコンピューター内で http://127.0.0.1 にアクセスしてみると言うことはあります。

> - ダイナミックルーティングでOSPF等？でルート優先度を決める時に判別に利用されるループバックの値とはまた別ものでしょうか？

「ループバックの値」とは何でしょうか？一般にルートの優先度を決める値はコストまたはメトリックです。もし、このことであれば、ループバックのは何の関係もありません。

Comment: この度はご解答ありがとうございました！！初めてここで質問をしたのでこんなに丁寧な回答がいただけると思っていなかったので感動しております。

Answer (score 0):

まず、ループバックインターフェースとループバックアドレスは直接対応するものではないです。
ここを正しく理解してください。

通常ループバックアドレスはループバックインターフェースに設定しますが、ループバックインターフェースには任意のアドレスが振れますし、ループバックアドレスが機能するためにはループバックインターフェースが必須というわけでもありません。

> １：「IPアドレスを仮想的に複数所有する事ができ物理的機器が動作している限りループバックインターフェイスは機能している為、物理的インターフェイスの予備として仮想的にルーティングしておくことができる」

これはループバックインターフェースの話です。

たとえば、大抵のルータでは、物理インターフェースが停止するとそのインターフェースに割り当てられたIPアドレスには通信できなくなります。冗長構成とかLAN側インターフェースがリンクダウンする可能性がある環境とかだと、このことが管理用のアドレスを何にするかという点で問題になります。

ここで、ループバックインターフェースに適当なアドレスを割り当ててルーティングを通しておけば、装置固有でダウンすることがない管理用アドレスとして便利です。

ネットワーク設計では割とカジュアルに使われるテクニックです。

> ２：TCP/IP通信がしっかり機能しているか確認する為のもの

これはループバックアドレスのはなしです。

ただ、どういう文脈でこの説明が書かれていたのかわかりませんが、何を言いたいのかはわかりません。

通常ループバックインターフェースはダウンすることはないのでそこに振られたアドレスは(ほぼ)確実に生きている、大抵どんな環境でも127.0.0.1である、というのは確かにテスト向きではありますが、逆に言うと、それで通信可能だからといって「で？」という話でもあります。

どちらかというと、確実にIPで通信ができることが期待できるので、

- 単一または異なるホストで動かすことが想定される複数のサービスで構成されたシステムが、ループバックアドレスを使うことでデフォルト設定でミニマムで機能するようにする
- 環境によらずユーザーに同一の手順で接続させることができる

みたいな使い方をされます。

> ３：「ループバックインターフェイスのIPアドレスとして登録できる範囲は127.0.0.0~127.255255.255まで」

これもループバックアドレスのはなしです。